# Load FXML components dynamically

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I've created a stage that contains a scene with 2 VBOX, each VBOX is supposed to contain 4 nodes that will be loaded dynamically from a FXML file.

I used the following function to load the nodes dynamically

```
@FXML VBox firstColumnBox; // will contain four loaded nodes
@FXML VBox secondColumnBox; // will also contain four loaded , so the scene will have a two columns screens with four nodes at right and four nodes at left

public void showPreviewOfCards(int size) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        try {
            FXMLLoader cardLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("CardEleveVerso.fxml"));
            AnchorPane cardRoot = cardLoader.load();

            if ((i == 0) || (i % 2 == 0)) {
                firstColumnBox.getChildren().add(cardRoot);
            } else {
                secondColumnBox.getChildren().add(cardRoot);
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

With the above function, I'm getting the expected result, but the problem is: "Performance". the app becomes too slow, and While using the profiler in netbeans, it almost takes up the full amount of the heap Size.

Then I changed it a little bit into this

```
@FXML VBox firstColumnBox;
@FXML VBox secondColumnBox;

public void showPreviewOfCards() {
    int size = listofStudentToPrint.size();

    try {
        FXMLLoader cardLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("CardeEleve.fxml"));
        AnchorPane card = (AnchorPane) cardLoader.load();

        CardeEleveController controller = (CardeEleveController) cardLoader.getController();

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            StudentModel student = listofStudentToPrint.get(i);
            student.setCardNo(String.valueOf(totalNoOfCard++));

            controller.setValues(student);

            if ((i == 0) || (i % 2 == 0)) {
                firstColumnBox.getChildren().add(card);
            } else {
                secondColumnBox.getChildren().add(card);
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This time, I've put the lines of codes responsible for loading the fxml outside of the "for loop" so that inside the loop I will only reuse the already loaded node by setting new values using the node's fxml controller.

And this is where the problem starts, in my two columns I only see one loaded node, no matter the number of nodes that I have added.

Here's the FXML file for the scene of the stage

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.net.URL?>
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.Image?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.TilePane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="612.0"
            styleClass="mainFxmlClass" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1"
            xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"
            fx:controller="monanocard.PrintCardRectoController">
  <stylesheets>
    <URL value="@printcardrecto.css"/>
  </stylesheets>
  <children>
    <BorderPane prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="635.0"
                AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0"
                AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
      <bottom>
        <HBox alignment="CENTER_RIGHT" prefHeight="37.0"
              prefWidth="648.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER_RIGHT">
          <children>
            <Button fx:id="btnPrint" mnemonicParsing="false"
                    prefHeight="32.0" prefWidth="121.0" style="-fx-background-color: 
green;" text="IMPRIMER" textFill="WHITE">
              <graphic>
                <ImageView fitHeight="22.0" fitWidth="31.0"
                           pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
                  <image>
                    <Image url="@../icons/ic_print.png"/>
                  </image>
                </ImageView>
              </graphic>
            </Button>
          </children>
          <BorderPane.margin>
            <Insets bottom="5.0" right="10.0" top="5.0"/>
          </BorderPane.margin>
        </HBox>
      </bottom>
      <center>
        <AnchorPane BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
          <BorderPane.margin>
            <Insets/>
          </BorderPane.margin>
          <children>
            <ScrollPane fx:id="scrollPane" fitToHeight="true"
                        fitToWidth="true">
              <content>
                <TilePane fx:id="twoColumnsContainer"
                          alignment="TOP_CENTER" hgap="1.0" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="- 
Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefColumns="2" prefRows="8"
                          prefWidth="655.0" tileAlignment="TOP_CENTER" vgap="1.0">
                  <children>
                    <VBox fx:id="secondColumnBox"
                          alignment="TOP_CENTER" maxWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="220.0"
                          prefWidth="315.0"/>
                    <VBox fx:id="firstColumnBox"
                          alignment="TOP_CENTER" maxWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="220.0"
                          prefWidth="315.0"/>
                  </children>
                </TilePane>
              </content>
            </ScrollPane>
          </children>
        </AnchorPane>
      </center>
    </BorderPane>
  </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Here's the FXML file that contains the design of the node  that is loaded dynamically

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.net.URL?>
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.Image?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity"
            prefHeight="176.0" prefWidth="310.0" style="-fx-background-color: white;" styleClass="card"
            xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"
            fx:controller="monanocard.CardeEleveController">
  <stylesheets>
    <URL value="@cardeeleve.css"/>
  </stylesheets>
  <children>
    <BorderPane layoutX="3.0" layoutY="3.0" prefHeight="156.0" prefWidth="307.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="2.0"
                AnchorPane.leftAnchor="2.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="2.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="2.0">
      <center>
        <AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" prefHeight="105.0" prefWidth="259.0" style="-fx-background-color: white;"
                    BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
          <children>
            <ImageView fx:id="imageProfile" fitHeight="84.0" fitWidth="87.0" layoutX="6.0" layoutY="8.0"
                       pickOnBounds="true">
              <image>
                <Image url="@../icons/ben.jpg"/>
              </image>
            </ImageView>
            <VBox alignment="TOP_CENTER" layoutX="100.0" layoutY="3.0" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="188.0"
                  spacing="2.0">
              <children>
                <HBox prefHeight="11.0" prefWidth="202.0">
                  <children>
                    <Label prefHeight="11.0" prefWidth="72.0" text="Nom">
                      <font>
                        <Font name="Roboto Bold" size="7.0"/>
                      </font>
                    </Label>
                    <Label fx:id="lblNom" prefHeight="4.0" prefWidth="97.0">
                      <font>
                        <Font name="System Bold" size="7.0"/>
                      </font>
                    </Label>
                  </children>
                </HBox>
                <HBox prefHeight="0.0" prefWidth="212.0">
                  <children>
                    <Label prefHeight="11.0" prefWidth="87.0" text="Postnom">
                      <font>
                        <Font name="Roboto Bold" size="7.0"/>
                      </font>
                    </Label>
                    <Label fx:id="lblPostnom" prefHeight="2.0" prefWidth="129.0">
                      <font>
                        <Font name="System Bold" size="7.0"/>
                      </font>
                    </Label>
                  </children>
                </HBox>
                <HBox prefHeight="0.0" prefWidth="212.0">
                  <children>
                    <Label prefHeight="11.0" prefWidth="86.0" text="Prenom">
                      <font>
                        <Font name="Roboto Black" size="7.0"/>
                      </font>
                    </Label>
                    <Label fx:id="lblPrenom" prefHeight="0.0" prefWidth="129.0">
                      <font>
                        <Font name="System Bold" size="7.0"/>
                      </font>
                    </Label>
                  </children>
                </HBox>
                <HBox prefHeight="0.0" prefWidth="212.0">
                  <children>
                    <Label prefHeight="11.0" prefWidth="84.0" text="Matricule">
                      <font>
                        <Font name="Roboto Bold" size="7.0"/>
                      </font>
                    </Label>
                    <Label fx:id="lblMatricule" prefHeight="0.0" prefWidth="129.0">
                      <font>
                        <Font name="System Bold" size="7.0"/>
                      </font>
                    </Label>
                  </children>
                </HBox>
                <HBox prefHeight="6.0" prefWidth="212.0">
                  <children>
                    <Label prefHeight="11.0" prefWidth="87.0" text="Classe">
                      <font>
                        <Font name="Roboto Black" size="7.0"/>
                      </font>
                    </Label>
                    <Label fx:id="lblClasse" prefHeight="9.0" prefWidth="129.0">
                      <font>
                        <Font name="System Bold" size="7.0"/>
                      </font>
                    </Label>
                  </children>
                </HBox>
                <HBox prefHeight="11.0" prefWidth="211.0">
                  <children>
                    <Label prefHeight="11.0" prefWidth="84.0" text="Sexe">
                      <font>
                        <Font name="Roboto Bold" size="7.0"/>
                      </font>
                    </Label>
                    <Label fx:id="lblSexe" prefHeight="0.0" prefWidth="129.0">
                      <font>
                        <Font name="System Bold" size="7.0"/>
                      </font>
                    </Label>
                  </children>
                </HBox>
                <HBox prefHeight="21.0" prefWidth="211.0">
                  <children>
                    <Label alignment="TOP_LEFT" prefHeight="16.0" prefWidth="70.0" text="Adresse">
                      <font>
                        <Font name="Roboto Black" size="7.0"/>
                      </font>
                    </Label>
                    <Label fx:id="lblAddresse" alignment="TOP_LEFT" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="101.0" wrapText="true">
                      <font>
                        <Font name="System Italic" size="5.0"/>
                      </font>
                    </Label>
                  </children>
                </HBox>
              </children>
              <padding>
                <Insets bottom="2.0" left="2.0" right="2.0" top="2.0"/>
              </padding>
            </VBox>
          </children>
        </AnchorPane>
      </center>
      <bottom>
        <VBox alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="18.0" prefWidth="295.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
          <BorderPane.margin>
            <Insets bottom="2.0" left="2.0" right="2.0" top="2.0"/>
          </BorderPane.margin>
          <children>
            <Label fx:id="lblValidity" alignment="CENTER" layoutX="100.0" prefHeight="23.0" prefWidth="295.0">
              <font>
                <Font name="Felix Titling" size="9.0"/>
              </font>
              <padding>
                <Insets bottom="2.0"/>
              </padding>
            </Label>
          </children>
        </VBox>
      </bottom>
      <top>
        <HBox maxWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="43.0" prefWidth="302.0" style="-fx-padding: 5;" styleClass="top"
              stylesheets="@cardeeleve.css" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
          <children>
            <ImageView fitHeight="29.0" fitWidth="36.0" pickOnBounds="true">
              <image>
                <Image url="@../icons/monano_logo.jpg"/>
              </image>
            </ImageView>
            <VBox prefHeight="29.0" prefWidth="212.0">
              <children>
                <Label alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="11.0" prefWidth="219.0" text="CS MONANO 1">
                  <font>
                    <Font name="Arial Black" size="10.0"/>
                  </font>
                </Label>
                <Label fx:id="lblCardNo" alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="11.0" prefWidth="220.0">
                  <font>
                    <Font name="Arial" size="8.0"/>
                  </font>
                </Label>
              </children>
            </VBox>
            <ImageView fitHeight="28.0" fitWidth="34.0" pickOnBounds="true">
              <image>
                <Image url="@../icons/rdc_flag.png"/>
              </image>
            </ImageView>
          </children>
        </HBox>
      </top>
    </BorderPane>
  </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

And the controller of the loaded Node

```
public class CardeEleveController implements Initializable {
    @FXML Label lblDevise;
    @FXML Label lblValidity;

    @FXML Label lblNom;
    @FXML Label lblPostnom;
    @FXML Label lblPrenom;
    @FXML Label lblClasse;
    @FXML Label lblSexe;
    @FXML Label lblAddresse;

    @FXML Label lblCardNo;
    @FXML Label lblMatricule;

    @FXML ImageView imageProfile;

    String serverAddress = FXMLDocumentController.configuration.get(ConfigurationHandler.OPTION_SERVER_ADDRESSE);
    String serverPort = FXMLDocumentController.configuration.get(ConfigurationHandler.OPTION_SERVER_PORT);
    String site = FXMLDocumentController.configuration.get(ConfigurationHandler.OPTION_SERVER_SITE);
    String photoSite = FXMLDocumentController.configuration.get(ConfigurationHandler.OPTION_PHOTO_SITE);
    String validite = FXMLDocumentController.configuration.get(ConfigurationHandler.OPTION_VALIDITY);

    private static boolean IS_OPERATION_MODE = false;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        String currentMode = FXMLDocumentController.CURRENT_MODE;
        if (currentMode.equalsIgnoreCase("operation")) {
            IS_OPERATION_MODE = true;
        }
    }

    public void setValues(StudentModel student) {
        if (student != null) {
            System.out.println("Controller setting values...");
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("------------------------------");
            System.out.println("NAME: " + student.getNom() + " " + student.getPostnom() + " " + student.getPrenom());
            System.out.println("------------------------------");

            String cardNoTxt = "Carte d'Eleve No " + generateCardNoBasedNoOfDigit(Integer.parseInt(student.getCardNo()));
            lblCardNo.setText(cardNoTxt);

            lblNom.setText(student.getNom());
            lblPostnom.setText(student.getPostnom());
            lblPrenom.setText(student.getPrenom());
            lblClasse.setText(student.getClasse());
            lblMatricule.setText(student.getMatricule());
            lblSexe.setText(student.getSexe());

            AddressModel address = student.getAddress();
            String addresseString = address.getAv() + " No." + address.getNo() + "Q. " + address.getQuartier() + "\n" + "C." + address.getCommune();
            lblAddresse.setText(addresseString);

            String imagePath = student.getPhotoUrl();
            if (IS_OPERATION_MODE) {
                //construct photo url
                String photoUrl = "http://" + serverAddress + ":" + serverPort + "/" + photoSite + "/" + Utility.STUDENT_IMAGE_DIRECTORY + "/" + imagePath;
                Image image = new Image(photoUrl, 100, 100, false, false);
                imageProfile.setImage(image);
            } else {
                // to use during formation Mode
                // load the image saved locally
                if (imagePath != null && !imagePath.isEmpty()) {
                    Image image = new Image("file:" + student.getPhotoUrl(), 100, 100, false, false);
                    imageProfile.setImage(image);
                }
            }

            if (validite != null) {
                // get the two values separated by :
                Scanner scanner = new Scanner(validite);
                scanner.useDelimiter(":");

                String fromDate = scanner.next();
                String toDate = scanner.next();

                String valideString = "Valide Du " + fromDate + " Au " + toDate;
                lblValidity.setText(valideString);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To summarise, I want to be able to load nodes dynamically without perfomance issues.

Comment: When you say the problem is performance, what precisely is the problem?  How fast (in milliseconds) was the performance of the system before you tried to optimize it and broke it?  How fast does it need to be (in milliseconds)?

Comment: by perfomance I meant, it's taking almost the full size provided for the heap size ( 490 MB out of 512 MB). and when I run the app  on a 32bit JDK platform, I'm getting an outOfMemoryException.

Comment: But your question states: "the app becomes too slow".  You might want to try using a tool such as https://visualvm.github.io diagnose your issues.

Comment: I ran some benchmarks on your code.  Loading the sub-fxml with a student card, took 250ms the first execution, then 40-50ms for each subsequent execution, so about 450ms to load eight cards.  Putting the main fxml loader into a start method and running that with eight cards then loaded into it and then showing the stage took 1.4s, so not exactly quick, but probably acceptable for most apps, especially for a first time stage load (subsequent executions, if required, would likely be much quicker).

Comment: To verify max memory usage, I ran the same test as described above, to render the main page with eight cards on it and set the JVM heap option to `-Xmx16M`, to specify a max heap size of 16MB and that ran perfectly fine.  So I don't know what the cause of your app slowness or heap usage is.  Only thing to note is that I used the following URL (`https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/5192e7cbcf2f72a847d6fb0d1552f049?s=48&amp;d=identicon&amp;r=PG`) for all images, so perhaps the images you are loading are really large when uncompressed to memory, but I don't know.

Comment: okay, thanks for your help and you r time. I was able to execute that stage on a 32bit jdk version by increasing the Heap Size too. I guess that was the source of the problem, as on 64bit jdk it was working perfectly.